# How to make CustomField selectable in Vaadin Table?

Tags: vaadin

I have a Vaadin Table and some cells are Labels and others are CustomFields. When I click on Label cell, the row is marked as selected - ok. However, when I click on CustomField cell, the row is not selected. How to modify CustomField implementation so that it is selectable in Table?

Answer (score 0):

try putting a layout around the customfield

Answer (score 0):

i don't have enough reputation to comment so i'll post an answer.
For Vaadin 8's Grid see the following issue https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/10425.
as tsuoanttila said the solution is to invoke `column.setWidgetEventsAllowed(true);`